# ModelState Binding issue Asp.Net 6

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to create a Menu for different Roles but when i choose the menu and role to create a Role_has_menu something is missing and ModelState said valid = false. This is the method i am using

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,MenuID,RoleID")] RoleHasMenu roleHasMenu)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     _context.Add(roleHasMenu);
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
     return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
  }

  ViewData["MenuID"] = new SelectList(_context.Menu, "ID", "FullName", roleHasMenu.MenuID);
  ViewData["RoleID"] = new SelectList(_context.Role, "ID", "Name", roleHasMenu.RoleID);
  return View(roleHasMenu);
}
```

[Model Binding error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pijwz.png)

I have the same code in other project and it works but this time i am using Visual Studio EF6 and a MySQL database instead of SQLserver

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

put your code in try -catch ,so in the exception you can find where your model is not valid